# Get table row object from table or vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey guys I'm creating a jquery plugin and I'm trying to either get the table row selector from table or the table from table row selector.

```
$("#table tr").myPlugin();

$("#table").myPlugin();
```

Basically within the plugin I need to access the table selector or row selector.  So within the first version with the row I need this.

```
var table = $('#table');
```

Or within the regular table version I need this.

```
var row = $('#table tr');
```

How would I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the plugin this.selector will give you the selector string, or the selector method that was used, like .children(td). this.context will give you the original context of the selector.

```
$('tr').children('td');

//inside plugin
this.selector; // "children(td)"
this.context;  // "tr"
this.prevObject; //[tr] parent table row
```

you can play around with different selectors here: http://jsfiddle.net/MkCxD/